# Pandas installation failed with error: numpy-1.24.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl is invalid

Tags: python, pandas, windows, numpy

I am trying to install Pandas on my python 3.11.2 on Windows 11 and received below error. Tried to google for an answer but failed to find anything that helps.

```
.\pip.exe install pandas

......

Collecting numpy>=1.21.0
  Downloading numpy-1.24.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (14.8 MB)
     ---------------------------------------  14.8/14.8 MB 2.8 MB/s eta 0:00:01
ERROR: Wheel 'numpy' located at C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-ufge3qs_\numpy-1.24.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl is invalid.
```

I am rather new to python, not sure what could break the installation. Appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find a work around by installing numpy before pandas, however still not sure why it failed with wheel.

```
.\pip.exe install numpy
.\pip.exe install pandas
```